# unable to update correct image data (binary) into image type column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

SQL Server 2012

```
Update [dbo].[TestTable] 
Set [TESTFILE]= 0xD0CF11E0A1B11AE10000000000000000000000000000000 
where FILETYPE = 7
```

here column **TESTFILE** is 'image' datatype

After running the above statement, the data under the TESTFILE column looks like **0x0D0CF11E0A1B11AE10000000000000000000000000000000** where it is adding extra digit '0' infront of 'DOC' and this fails my application functionality.

Also tried following way but having the same issue.

```
declare @imageData VARBINARY(MAX)
set @imageData = 0xD0CF11E0A1B11AE10000000000000000000000000000000
Update [dbo].[TestTable] 
Set [TESTFILE]= @imageData
where FILETYPE = 3
```

Any ideas on how to avoid appending extra digits ?

Comment: The smallest unit a `varbinary` can address is a byte (8 bits) but your input is one nibble (4 bits) short, that's why it's left padded with that zero nibble. Change your application to work in full bytes. Or also store a offset in bits, retrieve it too and have your application ignore that offset bits. I don't think there's a way to make `varbinary` address less than a byte.